# SIGNAL SLOT in QT

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slot

I wrote a simple QT calculator in VS2013. I used the signal `released()` to call my slots, but my slot won't work. Maybe my signal never triggered. I'm new to QT, and I don't know what I did wrong.

My class has this property:

```
class Calculator : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    Calculator(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Calculator();

private slots:
    void Calculator::two();
private:
    QLabel *lable;  
    QPushButton *two_button;
    QString value;
    QString total;
    int fnum;
    int snum;
    bool addbool;
    bool subtractbool;
    bool multiplybool;
    bool devidebool;
};
```

This is my line of code for connecting the signal to the slot:

```
one_button = new QPushButton("2", this);

connect(two_button, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(two()));
```

and my slot is

```
void Calculator::two()
{
    value = value+"2";
    lable->setText(value);
}
```

I put a breakpoint in my slot, but it never hit the breakpoint.

Comment: did you mean to use `clicked()` instead of `released()`?

Comment: @Mike release should also be called though I guess when you click the button.

Comment: you declared your slot wrong: not `void Calculator::two();` but `void two();`

Comment: Typo at `one_button = new QPushButton("2",this);` but `connect(two_button,SIGNAL(re...`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check the result of the `connect` function. Your slot needs to be defined the same way you provide it to `connect` if you're using the old signal/slot syntax, so

```
// this seems to be a non-standard extension of MSVC
// doesn't even compile under gcc, clang
void Calculator::two();
```

should become

```
void two();
```

But you should use the syntax introduced with Qt 5:

```
connect(two_button, &QPushButton::released, this, &Calculator::two);
```

and it wouldn't have mattered.

Comment: Ah I was just starting to write an answer to mention the new syntax ;)